# Unable to access MYSQL database from application in minikube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am new in Kubernetes, I deployed a web app and MySQL db on Minikube. I can access frontend but am unable to access the database

```
ConnectionProvider.java
static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:3306/jspdemoproject";
static String user = "${DB_USER}";
static String pass = "${DB_PASS}";
```

These are the variables I have modified in my java code.

Below is the yml configuration for an application

```
       jspweb.yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: jspweb
      labels:
        app: jspweb
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: jspweb
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: jspweb
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: jspweb
            image: kubesk071/jspapp:k8s
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-config
                  key: db-host
    
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jspdb-secret
                  key: username
    
            - name: DB_PASS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jspdb-secret
                  key: password
    
    
    ---
  #service file for web
    
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: jspweb-service
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      selector:
        app: jspweb
      ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
        nodePort: 30005
```

Below is the yml configurations for database

```
  jspdb-deploy.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jspdb
  labels:
    app: jspdb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jspdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jspdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jspdb
        image: kubesk071/jspdb:k8s
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:


        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: jspdb-secret
              key: username

        - name: DB_PASS
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: jspdb-secret
              key: password

---

#service file for db
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jspdb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: jspdb
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
```

Hostname configuration file

```
jsp-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-config
data:
  db-host: jspdb-service
```

I checked the application log. it is showing below error.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I am using the default namespace. Don't know where I am making a mistake.

```
Output for kubectl get all 

NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/jspdb-dd88566c-fxhlr      1/1     Running   0          4m10s
pod/jspweb-75c599d887-v7dvl   1/1     Running   0          3m55s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/jspdb-service    ClusterIP   10.96.19.46     <none>        3306/TCP         4m10s
service/jspweb-service   NodePort    10.111.42.254   <none>        8080:30005/TCP   3m55s
service/kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          7m46s

NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/jspdb    1/1     1            1           4m10s
deployment.apps/jspweb   1/1     1            1           3m55s

NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/jspdb-dd88566c      1         1         1       4m10s
replicaset.apps/jspweb-75c599d887   1         1         1       3m55s


Output for kubectl get pods -o wide 

NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
jspdb-dd88566c-fxhlr      1/1     Running   0          6m14s   10.244.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
jspweb-75c599d887-v7dvl   1/1     Running   0          5m59s   10.244.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

I changed hostname to jspdb-service.default.svc.cluster.local but still no luck

```
PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/bin:/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=jspweb-75c599d887-7ww9f
DB_HOST=jspdb-service.default.svc.cluster.local
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=12345678
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
JSPWEB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.102.147.146
JSPWEB_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.102.147.146:8080
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
JSPDB_SERVICE_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT=3306
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
JSPDB_SERVICE_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR=10.104.105.191
JSPWEB_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT=8080
JSPDB_SERVICE_PORT_3306_TCP_PROTO=tcp
JSPWEB_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP=tcp://10.102.147.146:8080
JSPWEB_SERVICE_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR=10.102.147.146
JSPDB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.104.105.191
JSPDB_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=3306
JSPDB_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.104.105.191:3306
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.21+9
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
TOMCAT_NATIVE_LIBDIR=/usr/local/tomcat/native-jni-lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/tomcat/native-jni-lib
GPG_KEYS=48F8E69F6390C9F25CFEDCD268248959359E722B A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7 DCFD35E0BF8CA7344752DE8B6FB21E8933C60243
TOMCAT_MAJOR=9
TOMCAT_VERSION=9.0.84
TOMCAT_SHA512=85a42ab5e7e4cb1923888e96a78a0f277a870d06e76147a95457878c124001c9a317eade4ad69c249a460ffe2cbefe894022b84389cdf33038bc456e3699c8e3
HOME=/root
```

I checked the database pod, database, and tables are created inside it but I'm unable to access it through the application pod.

Comment: when list pods what do you see ?

Comment: Can you please run `kubectl exec -it jspweb-75c599d887-v7dvl -- env`  it should show the values of `DB_HOST` , `DB_USER` and `DB_PASS` among the output, and If you can see their values, can you edit  the value of `db-host` inside the configmaps to the FQDN ofd db service  i.e `jspdb-service.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: I tried to change hostname in configmap file and relaunched minikube but still no luck

Comment: And you can see the env values inside the pod ?

Comment: yes I have added output in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256380/discussion-between-saifeddine-rajhi-and-shubham-kumbhar).